# Possible to pass a closure to usort in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, closures, usort

I have an array sorting function as follows:

```
public function sortAscending($accounts)
{
    function ascending($accountA, $accountB) {
        if ($accountA['AmountUntilNextTarget'] == $accountB['AmountUntilNextTarget']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($accountA['AmountUntilNextTarget'] < $accountB['AmountUntilNextTarget']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    usort($accounts, $ascending);

    return $accounts;
}
```

Clearly this is not ideal as it is hard-coding the key to search for.  I thought I would make this generic by passing the key as a param to outside function, however this is then out-of-scope in the inner function.  I tried to get around this by using a closure, which would have access to the param, instead of an inner function as follows:

```
public function sortAscending($accounts, $key)
{
    $ascending = function($accountA, $accountB) {
        if ($accountsA[$key] == $accountB[$key]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($accountA[$key] < $accountB[$key]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    usort($accounts, $ascending);

    return $accounts;
}
```

However usort() only accepts a function name, so this doesn't work.  Can anyone see a (better?) way of achieving this?

Comment: `usort` accepts a `callback` parameter, which can be a closure. The obvious error in your code is the missing `;` after the function definition. Maybe that is the cause of the error.

Comment: Apart from a missing `;`, `$key` is also not in the scope of your closure. You should use it: `$ascending = function($acciontA, $accountB) use($key) { ..`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- When defining closures, you can use the `use` keyword to let the function "see" a certain variable (or variables). See also the [PHP documentation about Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-154).

> Closures may also inherit variables
>   from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be declared in the
>   function header. Inheriting variables
>   from the parent scope is not the same
>   as using global variables. Global
>   variables exist in the global scope,
>   which is the same no matter what
>   function is executing. The parent
>   scope of a closure is the function in
>   which the closure was declared (not
>   necessarily the function it was called
>   from).

- Please also note that defining a closure and assigning it to a variable is a normal assignment operation, so you will need the `;` after the closing `}` of the closure.

After making these changes your code would look like this (and should work fine):

```
public function sortAscending($accounts, $key)
{
    $ascending = function($accountA, $accountB) use ($key) {
        if ($accountsA[$key] == $accountB[$key]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($accountA[$key] < $accountB[$key]) ? -1 : 1;
    };
    usort($accounts, $ascending);

    return $accounts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bazmegakapa and others for your quick reply, this is really helpful.  Apologies for the missing semi-colon I hadn't picked up on that, school boy error.

Answer (score 6):

To clarify this - and code it like a closure - and use the PHP7 spaceship operator - and correct a typo in line 4 of the first answer, skip the $ascending variable:

```
public function sortAscending($accounts, $key)
{
    usort($accounts, function($accA, $accB) use ($key) {
        return $accA[$key] <=> $accB[$key];
    });
    return $accounts;
}
```